# Appropriate HTTP status code for case when only one submission per user is allowed

Tags: api, rest, http-status-code-403, http-status-codes

I'm designing an endpoint for my API where only one submission is allowed per user. After reading the specification and trying to find the best response, I am hesitantly planning on using a *403 - Forbidden* when the user attempts to submit a second one:

> 10.4.4 403 Forbidden
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead.

I was always under the impression though that 403s where meant to be an access response - not necessarily something that responds to state issues. Is this correct? Or is there a better status code I should be using here?

Comment: The two options that I could see are sending a 403 or a [429](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6585#section-4). Honestly, neither would be a perfect fit for what you're trying to do, though, but either would be acceptable for what you want to report.

Comment: Interesting. I never used a 429 before, but, yeah, it almost fits:

The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). Like you know, this isn't a rate limit issue, but a state issue, but I think this might explain the error to the end user in a bit more detail.

Comment: In your API, are you returning only the status code, or are you including a status object as well? Assuming JSON, you could send a status code of 403 and content of `{"status": {"code": 403, "message": "This account has already made a submission"}}` so that the consumer can either honor the status code, honor the content or both.

Answer (score 1):

I've always `403` with authorization/authentication issues so I'm puzzled a bit ;) Below is the list of codes I'd take into consideration:

- `403 Forbidden` - (as mentioned above)
- `409 Conflict` - since a resource is in a given state that can't be changed it also a good status to notify the user about the problems.

And just a curiosity:

- `410 Gone` - request can be sent exactly once so the endpoint may be not available for subsequent requests. I do not consider it as good idea, since the endpoint is still available but will not be processing request from particular user. Hmm.. Might be considered weird.

I'd vouch for `403` or `409` and eventually will use rather `409`. `429` seems not to be a good idea because it's rather associated with network (broadband, throughput) problems rather than with resource itself.